# JavaFX DatePicker Bug?

Tags: java, swing, datepicker, javafx-8

I have run into a weird issue that I am not able to provide a simple working example for unfortunately.

I have a third party library that I am using in my project which is Swing Based.  This provides me a Java based image viewer.  The structure of the window is the following:

```
JavaFX Stage
   -> SwingNode
       -> Viewer Object
```

There are times when a user may split a document into two.  When this happens my vendor provided me a callback so I can set my meta data values on the object before sending it to my CMS system.

The callback is a JavaFX Scene which is displayed on Swing Layered Panel [I think that is the class - we don't use Swing].

This is the structure when it opens the pane

```
JavaFX Stage
   -> SwingNode
       -> Viewer Object
          --> JavaFX Embedded Window [which is the Swing pane]
             --> JavaFX Scene
                 -->DatePicker
```

When this scene is displayed, it all renders correctly - however, the datepicker doesn't allow me to select a date with the Mouse. It doesn't register the click on the extended calendar.  Not sure why.

Is there a way to hook into the click handler of the calendar to be the first in the chain?

Thanks

Comment: You have a `DatePicker` inside a JavaFX scene, displayed inside some AWT/Swing component (so wrapped in a `JFXPanel`), which itself is wrapped in a `SwingNode` and embedded in a JavaFX stage? So in other words you have JavaFX embedded in Swing embedded in JavaFX? I don't think the API was really designed for nested embedding like that. I'm not sure how event handling would work, and your thread management must be pretty horrendous.

Comment: So far - it works just fine since it's just used to display an image.  For the most part it's just a swing node on a Java FX Scene in a swingnode - but in this case, I need to hook in a callback.  All the event handling looks right, except this one piece.  Is there a way to put an eventFilter for mouse clicked on the calendar control?

Comment: Umm... maybe? You could perhaps use a lookup. Or a cell factory on the date picker that added event filters to the date cells. But I would strongly recommend looking for a way to either display the data picker in the "top level" JavaFX, or use a Swing/AWT date picker control instead; either way avoiding the double-embedding of two independent frameworks (because that is really doomed to fail, imho).

Comment: My next step is to remove the datepicker and provide a control which formats the text as a date.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to apply a mask on a textfield?  I haven't used the TextFormatter - but I am assuming that would work.  Basically, have it add the "/" as the user types and prevent non numeric entries and force numbers only?